# Is there a way to make XmlDocument parsing less strict

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am making a program that will store its data in an XML file. When people write XML they can make subtle mistakes, like ending a comment with `-` so it looks like `<!-- comment --->` or adding a `</>`inside an attribute. Naturally, the XML still can be read all right, but trying to input this text into XmlDocument will give a syntax error (and it wont be parsed).

Is there a way to make XmlDocument less strict and make it ignore violations of the standard that do not make the document unparseable? For example, its clear that `<!-- comment --->` is still a comment even though it contains `-` at the end which is against the standard specification).

Comment: In other words, make it more HTML.

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. Give people tools to generate the XML instead of asking them to handcraft it. XML is not designed to be handed edited by the average user.

Comment: If you do start allowing slopping input, then someone is going to try opening one of the XML files in another pieces of software and it will fail.

Comment: But people already did make the XML file. Wether or not it was designed, they did. And now i need to parse that file. I dont want to allow sloppy input, i want my program to parse the file once and then if user works in my program it will output strictly conformant Xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XML parsers are expected to reject input that is not valid XML.

You may try your luck preprocessing the invalid files by [Tidy](http://tidynet.sourceforge.net/), but better simply make sure the input is valid.

Here's an example usage. Tidy will fix your comments and do some escaping, but an extra opening < will break things up more often than not - guessing in that case is simply too much to ask.

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.Options.FixComments = true;
tidy.Options.XmlTags = true;
tidy.Options.XmlOut = true;

string invalid = "<root>< <!--comment--->></root>";
MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(invalid));
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
tidy.Parse(input, output, new TidyMessageCollection());
// TODO check the messages

string repaired = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
```

Comment: How do i "make sure"? User already have written an XML file, how do i "make sure" he did it right?

Comment: As a user of the XML parser, you're required to only pass it valid XML (otherwise it will throw you a nice exception). If you only have an invalid one, you have to either fix it before you pass it to the parser, or you can't use the XML parser at all.

Comment: That i undestand. I thought that "parser" MAYBE includes fixing simple mistakes and so in order to not invent the wheel i asked. If it doesnt, then of course i'll make a fixer myself

Comment: Right. Not the typical parser, that's why I'm suggesting tidy - a tool that was initially made for parsing/repairing messed up HTML markup, but may help in your case, too.

Comment: Btw, i think Tidy is what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with Tidy.Net? How do i make it not add lines after elements? It adds a blank line after every element

Comment: I've only had a quick look into the code, but the .net version doesn't seem to have an option for that. You'll probably have to override that in code if it matters (it shouldn't matter, if you're only serving the XML to the parser).

Comment: Yes, i know it doesnt matter in this exact case, still was willing to know if its possible. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

No, and that's a good thing.

XML is a strict format, the solution here is to have correct (corrected) input.

All XML tools are very picky, by design. You might have some luck with an XMLReeader and fixing or rejecting faulty elements.

But it's far better to create the XML with a suitable tool. Quite a few of them are named [XmlPad](https://www.google.nl/search?q=xmlpad&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Well, that's not. Computers are made to serve people, not the other way around. Yes a person made a mistake when creating an Xml file, but now i want my program to accept it and fix the mistakes for him, not ask him to do it. Too bad .Net framework doesnt know how to do it. It seems that i'll have to manually parse the Xml then...

Comment: A person should not be creating XML with NotePad. There is the error. Download [an XmlPad](https://www.google.nl/search?q=xmlpad&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: the C# compiler gives you an error if you write `fro` instead of `for`. Is it bad that the IDE doesn't correct that as well?

Comment: @Istrebitel - this is not a limitation of the .Net framework; xml parsers in any library/language generally will not accept invalid xml.

Comment: There's a design trade-off in the decision to make XML parsing strict: it means the parser never has to guess what the user intended, so it rejects the document rather than guessing wrong. There's nothing in the specs to stop someone writing a utility that tries to convert "bad XML" into "good XML", but few people have attempted it, and that's because the culture is to get the XML right at source rather than fix it later.

Comment: Well, i am not God so i cannot control who uses what to create XML. The user already did create an XML by hand and now there are only two ways out - my program tells him "fix it by hand then come back" or fixes it for him.

Comment: That just means your program is part of a system that was designed wrong. But you might find an Xml Tool/Editor that you can run in cmdline mode for cleanup.

Comment: Yes, the system was designed wrong, i agree, but knowing that doesnt solve the problem. Its like, you might think that your country's legislative system is designed wrong, or specific law X is designed wrong, but having that opinion does not make you exempt from complying to its laws.